# Mass hyperlink of PDF documents to excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

For tax audit reasons, I need to hyperlink hundreds of PDF files into an excel document.  Each PDF has a unique voucher number, which corresponds to the same unique voucher number in the source excel document.

I had software (LineLink) that would do this, but it is no longer available.  Is there a way to automatically hyperlink a single PDF to a single cell in Excel without doing it manually?  The LineLink tool could accomplish this in less than a minute (depending on how many files there were).

Thank you

Comment: Are all of the PDFs in the same folder? Or, are there at least large groups of them? If you have all the voucher numbers in excel, and all the files are pretty much in the same place, you could probably accomplish this with a formula.

Comment: Yes, all the PDFs are in the same folder.  I've been able to use =Hyperlink with the path, but instead of bringing up the actual picture file, it takes me to the folder where the PDFs are, and then I have to search for the voucher number.  I'm hoping to click on the underscored number and bring up the PDF directly.

Comment: So the pdf filenames are all *just* the voucher number? Is the voucher number always the same length?

Comment: @wysiwyg beat me to it, but we were both on the same train of thought. Their answer is what I would recommend as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, assuming the pdf filenames are *only* the voucher number and always the same length. (I'm a bit short on time right now so comment if you need clarification and I will try to edit.)

First open a command window in the directory containing the pdf files. Run the following command to generate a list of all pdf files with their full paths:
`dir /b /s /a:-D *.pdf > listpdf.txt`

Open the generated text file, select all, copy and paste into Column C of a new sheet in your Excel file.

In cell A1 of that sheet, enter the following formula to extract the voucher number. Change `3` to however many characters the voucher number is:

`=LEFT(RIGHT(C1,7),3)`

Now just enter `=HYPERLINK(C1)` in B1, and double click the fill handles on cells A1 and B1 to autofill the formulas for all your data.

---

***EDIT***

Just re-read your question and re-thought my answer. You should be able to do this much simpler. Just use this formula:
`=HYPERLINK("C:\<path to pdf file directory>"&A1&".pdf")`

Comment: You've no idea the size of the happy dance I'm doing right now!!  This is PERFECT, and works PERFECTLY!!  The link isn't pretty in the file, but it works, it works, IT WORKS!!  Thank you for your help - such a simple answer to a major problem!  Thank you wysiwyg!!!!!

Comment: And to answer the question, Yes, all the vouchers are an 8-digit number, unique to a single invoice, stored in a single folder.

Comment: Happy to help, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with the formula =HYPERLINK(...)

Comment: I've started withe the =Hyperlink formula, using the path to the folder in first box.  I need to be able to click on the underlined number and bring up the picture.  Right now the underlined number only takes me to the folder where the files are located and then I have to look for them individually.

Comment: the first box should be the path and file name (including extension).